# how to link accounts nestjs passportjs?

Tags: passport.js, nestjs

Trying to link social networks

`acebook.stratedy.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class FacebookStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'facebook') {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.FB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FB_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.URL + '/auth/facebook/callback',
      profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos'],
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }

  async validate(
    req: Request,
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: (error: any, user: any, info?: any) => void,
  ): Promise<void> {
    console.log('facebook_req', req.user); // undefined
    const userInfo: IUserPassport = {
      socialID: profile.id,
      typeAuth: EUserTypeAuth.FACEBOOK,
      fullname: profile.displayName,
      avatar: profile.photos[0].value,
    };

    const createdUser: UserEntity = await this.authService.createUser(userInfo);

    const jwtAccessToken: string = await this.authService.createJwtAccessToken({
      sub: createdUser.id.toString(),
      social_id: createdUser.socialID,
      type: createdUser.typeAuth,
    });

    return done(null, jwtAccessToken);
  }
}
```

i want to get logged in user but instead get `undefined` (`req.user`)

`auth.controller.ts`

```js
  @Get('/facebook')
  @UseGuards(FacebookAuthGuard)
  async facebookLogin(): Promise<any> {
    return HttpStatus.OK;
  }

  @Get('/facebook/callback')
  @UseGuards(FacebookAuthGuard)
  async facebookLoginRedirect(@Req() req: Request): Promise<any> {
    return this.authService.authCallback(req);
  }
```

I wanted to get req.user to check for authorization and then choose whether to register a new user or add to an existing one.

how can i get an authorized user? Are there examples?

Comment: I think you would need to handle this in the `/facebook/callback` handler, not the strategy. The value of `req.user` is created from the return value of `validate`, so `req.user` won’t be available within the `validate` callback. The root of the problem is getting the local user ID from the current session so you can link them. You might have to implement an extra guard to pass this information.

Comment: any progress on this?